# LDAP server signing protocol

Tags: windows, ldap, protocols

I need to implement Microsoft's LDAP server signing protocol to be able to connect to AD servers that require it but can't find this protocol description. Is there a protocol description published somewhere?

Comment: Did you try Google? First hit is an [MS Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935834).

Comment: Yes I tried but unfortunately is describes how to turn it on in Windows settings but not how to implement it. I need a protocol description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is done from LDAP it is implemented from a SASL mechanism implementation and utilizes [GSS-SPNEGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO)/[GSSAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSSAPI).

Perhaps the first problem is to determine "What is Signing?"

Which AFIK, Signing implies:
Clients that are signed SASL (Negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, or Digest) or LDAP binds over a SSL/TLS connection.

So no simple binds or un-signed (ie un-encrypted) SASL mechanisms.

The Negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, or Digest are implemented from GSSAPI/SPNEGO.